How to load properties from application.properties with @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
I am trying to learn Spring Boot and I was trying to get a solid understanding about testing.
I am aware that @SpringBootTest loads the full context I do not want to do that.
I know that the slice tests (i.e: @WebMvcTest, @JdbcTest) internally use @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class),
What if i just want a simple integrated test with my own beans and I also want to load configuration properties, is it possible to use this with the @Value ?
I know I can use ReflectionTestUtils but I thought since Spring Extension loads a test context, it should get the application.properties file ?
So far I am getting a very strange result with @Value, it gets the key instead of the value. It works perfectly with @SpringBootTest so I know the properties are loaded fine when the full application.
Here is my code:
application.properties in src/test/resources:
misc.test-prop-value=testPropValue

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class ConfigPropertiesTest {
@Value( value = "${misc.test-prop-value}")
private String testPropValue;


@Value("${some.non.existent.value}")
private String nonExistentValue;

@Test
void testNonExistentValue() {
    assertNull(nonExistentValue); // Fails, the value is: ${some.non.existent.value}
}

@Test
public void testConfigProperties() {
    assertEquals("testPropValue", testPropValue); //Fails, the value is: ${misc.test-prop-value}
}

}
Why is the @Value picking up the key itself ?
It works perfectly with @SpringBootTest,
I thought since @SpringExtension loads an application context:
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class SpringExtensionBasicTest {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() throws Exception {
        //GenericApplicationContext instance:
        System.out.println("Context instance: " + applicationContext.getClass());
        assertNotNull(applicationContext); // Test passes
    }



}

When I extend a base class that has @SpringBootTest,
Everything works fine, it loads the context, and there is even an error when the some.non.existent.value property not found.
But with the Spring Extension, the behaviour is weird.
Maybe this is a silly question, I can sense this is one of those things, where I am missing something so obvious in my face that no one has even explained it, but i am not getting it.
Also if I wanted my own slice test but I still want the .properties file to be loaded like it does with @JdbcTest for example, how would this work
Edit:
I got two of the tests to pass when using @TestPropertySource, but the non existent value that is null with @SpringBootTest, still shows the same key:
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestPropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
public class ConfigPropertiesTest  {

    @Value( value = "${misc.test-prop-value}")
    private String testPropValue;

    @Value("${family.mother}")
    private String mamaValue;

    /**
     * When a non-existent value is there,
     * It is not null for some strange reason,
     * But it still shows the key
     */
    @Value("${some.non.existent.value}")
    private String nonExistentValue;

    @Test
    void testNonExistentValue() {
        //Still shows ${some.non.existent.value}
        assertNull(nonExistentValue);
    }

    @Test
    void testPropValue1() {
        assertEquals("Mama-test", mamaValue); //Ok
    }

    @Test
    public void testConfigProperties() {
        assertEquals("testPropValue", testPropValue); //Ok
    }

}


I think your IgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders parameter is set to true. Otherwise, the absence of the some.non.existent.value property would result in an error
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'some.non.existent.value' in value "${some.non.existent.value}"

For example, if you create a bean like this:
    @Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfig() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        configurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return configurer;
    }

then if Spring cannot find the some.non.existent.value property for the nonExistentValue field, it will write string "${some.non.existent.value}" to that field.
I think it makes sense for you to set a default value for the nonExistentValue field using this code:
    @Value("${some.non.existent.value:#{null}}")
    private String nonExistentValue;


Oh okay, thank you for this, i will look at it now so i would need to create this in a config file i guess and @Import the config file inside the test ?

@theMyth if you want nonExistentValue to contain null then just add #{null} to the placeholder

Thank you, Just a small side question if I may please, without @TestPropertySource, the Spring Extension can’t pick up the property file by itself ??

@theMyth Spring Boot automatically loads a properties file named application-test.properties or application-test.yml when running tests if spring.profiles.active=test is specified in application.properties

@theMyth If you are using a development environment such as IntelliJ IDEA or Eclipse, you can specify the active profile via the launch configuration settings: -Dspring.profiles.active=test

Thank you very much, Only thing is with slice tests like @JdbcTest, it automatically picks up application.properties, so I am not sure why Spring Extension cant
